# Using Intents to Launch another app to open a .vtk file

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-package-managers

I am currently working on an app in Android, and in my app, the user can browse and select a .vtk file.

I have also installed an app called "KiwiViewer," which opens these .vtk files. When I manually go through my tablet, and click on .vtk files using a file managing app, KiwiViewer opens these .vtk files with no problem.

I would like to have the same thing occur in my app. I would like the user's selected .vtk file to be opened by KiwiViewer. I know KiwiViewer's package ("com.kitware.KiwiViewer"), and I am able to open the app with an intent. However, I am unable to open the .vtk file I passed to the app.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.kitware.KiwiViewer"));
i.setData(Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString("ImageURI")));
startActivity(i);
```

I have checked, and the data being sent is valid (it isn't null, and it is definitely the right file.

I have also tried the following, but it doesn't work either:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setData(Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString("ImageURI")));
i.setPackage("com.kitware.KiwiViewer");
startActivity(i);
```

However, I get an "Activity Not Found Exception."

How can I launch KiwiViewer so that it opens the data I provide it?

**EDIT:** It seems that when I look at the URI path being supplied to KiwiViewer, it is /document/primary:ExperimentData/MHDImage.vtk. KiwiViewer says this does not exist. In reality, the path is /sdcard/ExperimentData/MHDImage.vtk. Any reason why the two would differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, after looking at the source code for KiwiViewer, that it needs a URI scheme of file, not content, to open the data. In addition, I had to manually extract the subdirectories ("ExperimentData/MHDImage.vtk") and concatenate it to "/sdcard/" to get KiwiViewer to open the data. I know that this hardcoding is frowned upon, but when I use the alternate to "/sdcard/" (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()), I do not get the correct directory.